# Flutter redirect to a new screen when a condition is true

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a flutter application like

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'network.dart';

void main() => runApp(HomePage());

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}


class _MyAppState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _message = '';
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  _register() {
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) => print(token));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getMessage();

    TestNetwork.checkNetwork().then((val){
          print(val);
    });
  }

  void getMessage(){
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on message $message');
      setState(() => _message = message["notification"]["title"]);
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on resume $message');
      setState(() => _message = message["notification"]["title"]);
    }, onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on launch $message');
      setState(() => _message = message["notification"]["title"]);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new MaterialApp(

        home: new Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Message: $_message"),
            OutlineButton(
              child: Text("Register My Devices"),
              onPressed: () {
                _register();
              },
            )

          ]),
        ),
      );

  }
}
```

I am calling a network checking functionality from another dart file, so

network.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

class TestNetwork {

static String mainWebServiceURL="http://mydmain.com/webservicepath/";

static Future<bool> checkNetwork() async {
  try{
      Map<String,String> _user = {};
      _user['name'] = "Username";
      final response= await http.post(mainWebServiceURL+'/index.php',
        body: _user,
      );
      if(response.statusCode==200)
        return Future.value(true);
        else
        // I want to redierct to another page in main.dart page
  }
  catch (_) {
    // I want to redierct to another page in main.dart page
  }

}

}
```

So my question is if `checkNetwork()` function fails or the response is "negative" then I want to redirect / show another page in main.dart or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(note:wrapping the below code in a zero-time delayed future is just to make sure that context will be ready when we use it)

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getMessage();

   Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
     TestNetwork.checkNetwork().then((val){
       Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx)=>MySuccessRoute()));
     },onError: (){
       Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx)=>MyFailureRoute()));
     });
   });
  }
```

Comment: I just want to check this network function from almost all pages. So I decided to do the if..else part inside the function

Comment: That would be a non-clean solution, mixing business logic with UI (since you will need in this case to pass context to your function which should know nothing about UI), so I recommend going with the solution in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for this, you can do one of these things:

1. Let your `checkNetwork` function return `true` or `false`, and then use this boolean value to determine which widget to use in the `home` field of the `MaterialApp` widget.
2. Create a new widget, maybe `SplashScreen` which will always be the one used in the `home` field of `MaterialApp`, and in this widget you `checkNetwork` and do the proper `Navigator.push()` according to the boolean result.

Personally I prefer method 2 because it can give you more control.